# What's the correct way of accessing input fields in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

So I have this application which uses Redux to store some data. Then I have the Search component, which I originally wanted to be a plain dumb component. However, there is an input field whose value I would like to access and pass on to do something with it. However, I am not sure how to manage the value of this input field, that is, how to access it & where to store the value. I want to use Redux and be consistent, so that's my main problem. I have found the following solution (which works), but this does not look like Redux to me anymore? Am I violating any Redux specific rules with this?

On the other hand, how would I do it with Redux? With a reducer & action etc. *just* for this one input field in one component? This seems like a bit too much, but please enlighten me!

```
class Search extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     username: ""
   };

    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
 }
  handleUsernameChange(evt) {
      console.log("Helo" + evt.target.value);
      this.setState({
          username: evt.target.value
      });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Hello" + e);
      /* Do something... */
  }


  render() {
    // Return JSX via render()
    return (
      <div className="">
        <h1>Youtube Link</h1>
        <input className="form-control" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}></input>
        <button className="btn btn-large btn-positive" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Download</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

// Export Search
export default Search
```

Comment: For smaller components which can be used in different context, it is a good idea to save such things in component's state rather than in redux store. If you still wanna save it in redux store, you can create an action which will do that for you.

Comment: thanks. would this make my component 'smart'? or would it still be fair to call it a 'dumb' component?

Comment: Precisely why the monikers of 'smart' and 'dumb' are, well, dumb.  From a tutorial I read through, I liked that authors notion of 'connected' and 'pure'. Pure is presentation only, 'Connected' is connected to a Store. If you're using state to manage your form, but not saving to a Store, I'd say that component is still Pure / dumb.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to use Redux and be consistent, so that's my main problem."

That's a valid reason to use Redux for this use case. But it is also fine to use combination of Redux and local component state in your application. I think this is a perfect example on when local component state is a good solution. I wrote a blog post on this topic. If you want, you can take a look here: http://blog.jakoblind.no/2017/02/08/is-using-a-mix-of-redux-state-and-react-local-component-state-ok/

Answer (score 0):

> On the other hand, how would I do it with Redux? With a reducer & action etc. just for this one input field in one component? This seems like a bit too much, but please enlighten me!

Yes, this is how you would do it with Redux.  If you need the the `username` value anywhere else in your app, then this is the approach you should take.

If you don't want to write your own actions and reducer and everything for it, you could look into [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/) to handle it for you, but it might be a bit overkill if there is not much other input required from the user.

If you only need it when you hit that button right below it, then what you have is fine as you can just raise your action with the value from the components state, e.g,

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Hello" + e);
    /* Do something... */
    this.props.downloadTheThing(this.state.username)
}
```

where `downloadTheThing` is mapped in your mapDispatchToProps function when connecting the component (assuming you are using react-redux).

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely fine to use local state in Redux.

From the code snippet you shared, you don't even need to use a local state.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.username = '';
  ...
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log('Hello ' + this.username);
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <input type="text" onChange={e => this.username = e.target.value} />
    ...
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input className="form-control" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}></input>
```

that is your input field. first thing todo when you work on input in react is to set the `value` and then apply onChange. with `value` we will assign the state of the input to the state of the component so we will get single source of truth.

since you want to work on redux store, I assume you already have your redux store, reducers and actions set in your application. reducers hold the state and you send message to reducers via `dispatch()`. You access to dispatch() on `this.props.dispatch()` once you define connect() (). By default, a connected component receives props.dispatch()

```
import React from "react"; //anywhere you are using jsx, u should import this
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import setInputAction from "relative path" //actions are the messages that you send to reducers. reducers change the state based on the actions.

//this allows you access to state in Redux-store via the props.
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    reduxState: state
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Search);
```

this code is kinda configuration of your component to communicate with the redux-store.

Now let's focus on input field.  we have to set the value:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      value={this.props.reduxState.input}// i assume you have `input:""` in the state. u can name anything you want.
      onChange={e => {
        this.props.dispatch(setInputAction(e.target.value));//we are sending e.target.value to the reducer via dispatch().
      }}
    />
```

setInputAction  is just an object that sent to reducer. Reducers are already defined what to do under certain actions. So you just send the message and reducer will change the state accordingly.